# Image Magick is there a better way to iterate over pdf pages (Convert PDF booklet to .jpg)

Tags: php, imagemagick

This is the code I've got and it works fine. I just don't believe it is the "best" way to do it.

```
<?
    $im = new imagick();
    $im->setResolution(10,10);
    $im->readimage('document.pdf');
    $pages = $im->getNumberImages();
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();

    for($i=0;$i<$pages;$i++) {
        $im = new imagick();
        $im->setResolution(100,100);
        $im->readimage('document.pdf['.$i.']');
        $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
        $im->writeImage($i.'.jpg');
        $im->clear();
        $im->destroy();
    }
?>
```

Anyone knows how to do it the best way? Please show me how.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will help someone.

My solution is to use the method [writeImages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimages.php). Make sure you set the *$adjoin* flag to false to get seperate files.

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution(100,100);
$im->readimage('document.pdf');
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->writeimages('document.jpg', false);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

It will result in *document-0.jpg, document-1.jpg, document-3.jpg* etc.

Comment: How about writing to another directory?

Comment: Figured it out, just provide directory together with file name. 
$im->writeimages('/directory/document.jpg', false);

Comment: Nice! Seems to be faster, too!

Comment: @RobbieP But what if you want to store all the image names in an array using the clean method?

Comment: @Max sorry for the late reply, but it may help someone else. There are two ways I can think of: http://codepad.org/JYAPxB1B